# IIS 7.5 with php on Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, php5

I have installed php 5.4.9 with iis 7.5 on Windows server 2008 R2 with web platform installer.

phpinfo() is working file. But when i upload our web pages getting error. 
Here I've attached error message. Please advice me about this issue.

I've checked Handler mappings. All are here are default settings only.

[image]

Comment: Your tags are mutually exclusive: windows 2008 runs IIS 7 and windows Vista runns IIS 7.5

Comment: @Stephane I coudn't get you

Comment: What version of IIS are you running exactly ? What version of windows exactly ? Because you cannot be running IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008

Comment: See this for a list of IIS version compared to Windows versions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224609

Comment: @Stephane I'm using Windows server 2008 R2 Standard and IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found some error on my web config file. Once I cleared, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check the default document: in your screenshot, you're not specifying any PHP file, just a path.

More detailed explanation:

By default, no modern web server will just serve a directory listing when the user doesn't specify a document but just a path (e.g. http://www.mysite.org/somefolder/) so they all have a parameter that specify what document in a folder should be considered the default one to serve if the URL isn't specific.

In IIS 7.5 (running on Windows 2008R2), that list is, by default, in this order:

default.htm
default.asp
index.htm
index.html
iisstart.htm
default.aspx

So either try to access to you main page explicitely http://www.mysite.org/somefolder/index.php) or add it to the list of default documents.

Comment: If we didn't specify anything it'll be look index.html , index.php like this. I hope that i understand your reply...